# Understanding BinaryObjects in ignite

Tags: java, ignite

I have some data which I'm going to store in `BinaryObject` format. I'm using `DataStreamer` to put data into cache and `StreamReceiver` to process them. Here is how I create `BinaryObject`:

```
String typeName; // Some arbitrary string, does not correspond to any FQCN
BinaryObjectBuilder bldr = ignite.binary().builder();
String key;
//init
IgniteDataStreamer<String, BinaryObject> strmr = ignite.dataStreamer(typeName);
//set receiver
strmr.addData(key, bldr.build());
```

But in the receiver code I have this:

```
@Override
public void receive(IgniteCache<String, BinaryObject> cache, Collection<Map.Entry<String, BinaryObject>> entries) throws IgniteException {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    BinaryObject value = entry.getValue(); //< ----Here is where problems come
    //...
}
```

In the bottom of stackTrace I got this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=-462125592]
```

What does it mean? Am I right that ignite try to deserialize binary object to some type, but did not found a class byt the type name I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `keepBinary` flag on the streamer prior to adding any data to it:

```
strmr.keepBinary(true);
```